# Socket.IO & Node/Express Configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I am trying to connect my front-end which is on a online text editor to my Node server. I am hitting network error `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` and it is not hitting the Socket IO listener. Please let me know what is causing this error & how to fix it. Thanks!

Here is the Node.js code:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.options('*', cors())   
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Oops, incorrect URL")
});
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.set('origins', '*:*');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
console.log("CONNECTED!")
});
```

Here is the front-end:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
var socket = io('https://myserver.com/', {secure: true});
socket.emit('chat message', "testing");
```

Comment: Node.js server is running on port 443, righ t?

Comment: It's running on Heroku, I'm not sure the port. Does that matter for Socket.IO?

Comment: because you define in frontend its run on port 443 `var socket = io('https://myserver.com/', {secure: true});`

Comment: I read the `{secure:true}` online as a potential fix. I'm not sure if I even need that. If I removed it, should it work?

Comment: try `var socket = io('http://myserver.com:1337', {secure: false});`

Comment: If you are trying to connect heroku app , you have to use either   var socket = io.connect(ws://blooming-chamber-76501.herokuapp.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket) or var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname)

Comment: @MohammadRaheem Since the frontend is not being server side rendered, would that work? Is there any way to do it without server side rendering?

Comment: After doing this, I got a new error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackblitz.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http:/myapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MIaEqf3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.